# Vsphere/Vmware and Consul cluster auto join

Tags: vmware, consul, vsphere, autodiscovery

I have already implemented Consul cluster in AWS with AutoJoin and EC2 tagging.

https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/cloud-auto-join.html

Now I am trying to do them same on a VMware/Vsphere environment. I have done everything as the tutorial describes, but the issue there is the TAGS. Seems that those tags which are generated from the UI are not the actual tags which Consul see. As far as I understood there are different tags which can only be applied via the REST API.

Has someone managed to make a consul cluster in Vsphere with auto-join function ? I have searched all over the internet for some user stories on this topic, but there is none.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So this work. It seems that the issue was on my side. I used a complicated password and it did not render it correctly. More info here:

https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/issues/4486